# What's your recommendation for a front end form validation library for MaterialUI with React?

Tags: web-development, validation

I'm building a small rails/vite/react/material UI project, and I've got a login form built, with client-side validation that basically just makes sure the fields have been set, and if not, will set the helper text with an error message and bail from any api call.

***See screenshots and component code below***

Right now I'm doing everything from scratch, e.g, setting the state on for each field onChange, and then onClick (for button) running a validation that checks if the state for each of these fields is correct.

### Question

I know this is the "typical" way of doing these things in react, but does anyone have a *favorite* front-end validation library they like to use with React and Material UI in Production? Do these front-end validation libraries feel like they speed up your build time?

### Login.jsx (Example component)

#### On Page Load

[image: Before client-side validation]

#### On Failed Validation

[image: After client-side validation]

#### Component Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Item from "@mui/material/Grid";
import LoginIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Login";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

import "./Login.scss";
const Login = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState();
  
  const [nameError, setNameError] = React.useState();
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = React.useState();
  
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = React.useState(false);

  const handleLoginSubmit = () => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    clearPreviousErrors();

    if (!validateForm()) {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
      return;
    }

    // TODO: Submit POST request to /api/v1/users/login
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    if (!name) setNameError("Name is required");
    if (!password) setPasswordError("Password is required");
    return name && password ? true : false;
  };

  const clearPreviousErrors = () => {
    setNameError();
    setPasswordError();
  }

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="md" className="Login">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Item>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Name"
              placeholder="Name"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value.trim())}
              error={nameError !== undefined}
              helperText={nameError}
              required
              fullWidth
            />
          </Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Item>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Password"
              placeholder="Password"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value.trim())}
              error={passwordError !== undefined}
              helperText={passwordError}
              required
              fullWidth
            />
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} className="Login__button-group">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                endIcon={<LoginIcon />}
                onClick={handleLoginSubmit}
                disabled={isSubmitting}
              >
                Login
              </Button>
              <Link to="/register" className="Login__register">
                Register
              </Link>
            </Stack>
          </Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/ will be better place to ask this question.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Unfortunately SO doesn't allow asking for recommendations... :( See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496948/whats-your-favorite-front-end-form-validation-library-for-material-ui-or-react).

Comment: In such case change your question, because "favorite" imply opinion based answer which IMHO will not be accepted here too.